# Error on collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I am having trouble in converting a uitable into collectionview.

I have the following code but it has error on "collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"May I know what;s the problem?

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

//  Return the number of rows in the section (the amount of items in our array)
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [pictureListData count];
}

//  Create / reuse a table cell and configure it for display
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Get the core data object we need to use to populate this table cell
    Pictures *currentCell = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: No visible@interface for "UICollectionView"declares the selector"dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. While the error arrow pointed at the word,"collectionView".

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong method name.  For UICollectionViews the method is:

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

So you need to change

```
UICollectionViewController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to

```
UICollectionViewController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I am not so sure how to use this code, can you further explain to me please? thanks.

Comment: @Clarence You just need to change the method to what I have in my edited code above

Comment: within the - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}???

Comment: Yes, you just tried to call the wrong method.  The signature for dequeueing a `UICollectionViewCell` is not exactly the same as for dequeueing a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @DanF why would apple name them slightly differently?

Comment: @cncool Without interviewing the software engineers at Apple, there's no real way to know for certain.  I'd assume they have a good reason, but its possible that engineering teams changed since the UITableView API was developed, so naming conventions might have changed as well